# can we use set,bag,map for non collection relationship

Tags: sql, nhibernate

Does set,bag while cascading is used for Ilist or Iset only.
What if the entity is not a list, just a non collection relationship.
In that case what should we use while cascading.

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking about cascading for non-collection relationships. If that's the case, please rephrase your question and title, it's not very clear...

Comment: do you know the answer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot use set, bag, list, idbag, or map for non-collection properties on an entity.

```
set             -> Iesi.Collections.ISet
bag, idbag, map -> System.Collections.IList
map             -> System.Collections.IDictionary
```

If you want to use cascade for a non-collection (many-to-one) relationship then yes you can. Here is a [blog post about many-to-one](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/09/nhibernate-mapping-ltmany-to-onegt.aspx) and [another about cascades](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/02/NHibernateCascadesTheDifferentBetweenAllAlldeleteorphansAndSaveupdate.aspx).